# How to debug Opera on Android?

Tags: android, console.log, android-debug, opera-mobile

I have a web app that doesn't work as expected on Opera on Android. How can I see the console logs?

On iOS, I can connect my device and inspect everything in Safari.

Comment: Is it UI that doesnt work? download opera on your desktop and from developer tools choose mobile view

Comment: No, for some reason the issue happens only on the physical phone.

Comment: Then I suggest connect the device and check logcat in android studio...

Answer (score 3):

It turns out it is the same way you do it on Chrome now.

1. You will first need to put your phone in developer mode.
2. Then in the developer mode options allow USB debugging.
3. Connect your Android device to the PC you want to use for debugging.
4. Open opera on your Android device and leave it running on a webpage.
5. Then open opera and put the following in the URL bar: opera://inspect/#devices
6. Once you see your device you should also see opera tab urls listed. Click    the inspect link below the address you want to view.
7. You should then get a view of your Android device and a developer tools view that includes the console.

It may take a while for your phone to show up in opera the first time you do it.